# Materialize CSS issue with loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

In the latest version of materialize css (0.98.2).
By removing the class active,the loader should ideally disappear but it isn't doing it. This issue wasn't present in the previous version.
The following is my html and js code.

```js
$scope.removeLoader = function() {

  $("#loaderId").removeClass('active');

}
```

```html
<div id="loaderId" class="row preloader-wrapper big active">
  <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
    <div class="circle-clipper left">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gap-patch">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle-clipper right">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The function removeLoader is being called and the class is being removed but the loader still continues to load. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you not just hide loader with `ng-show`?

Comment: @Leguest That is an option but I'd like to do it by toggling between the class active and curious as to why this stopped working in this version.

Comment: Check CSS styles of `.active` and default states. I think  `.acitve` has no styles for now.